# Checkbox check repeats in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have the following implementation of a custom ListView populated using a CursorAdapter:

```
private class CurAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

        public CurAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {

            super(context, c, flags);

        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            String name = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationDateFor")));
            String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imageUri"));



            holder.nametext.setText(name);
            setImage(image, holder.iv); 
            holder.chk.setOnClickListener(onchk);


        } 
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.group_list, null);

            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(holder);
            return view;

        }

        private View.OnClickListener onchk = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        };


        public class ViewHolder {
            TextView nametext;
            RoundedImageView iv; 
            CheckBox chk; 

            public ViewHolder(View view){

                iv = (RoundedImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                nametext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                chk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            }



        }

    }
```

I am using a Holder pattern to avoid repetition, but I get check-boxes checked at random while scrolling my list, what do I miss here?

Also I want to know how to store the values of clicked checkboxes in my onClick of the checkbox.

Comment: You have to save the state of the each checkbox somewhere in your code. An Hashmap is a good solution. Next you need to check or uncheck everytime you bind your view.

Comment: Oh that's a pain in the ass! Do you have any reference tut? I am still confused if my views are getting recycled and hold this residue, as I am using the holder pattern?

Comment: Yes but remember that ViewHolder pattern doesn't save you from recycling. It saves you from calling `findViewById` over and over again, causing your list to flicker. Android will call newView for the first visible views, next since the views will be the same (because it doesn't make sense to create 1000 views if you're just showing 10 on your screen for example) it will reuse them, that's why it will call bindView. Here you have the opportunity to change the content of a reused view. However, things like visibility and check state will not get changed unless you do so.

Comment: As for the tutorial I'm sure there are some out there. You just need to look for it as I don't have anyone on my hand right now :\

Comment: Thanks mate, Ill have a look there, bom dia!

Answer (score 0):

Just create an android project and do this step by step:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="showDialog"
    android:text="Click Here..." />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/techView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.multichoiceitem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final String[] items = { ".NET", "J2EE", "PHP", "Android", "DBMS", "JAVA",
        "C", "C++" };
String[] itemstemp;
boolean[] selected = new boolean[items.length];
String selectedTech = "Selected Tech - ";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    itemstemp = new String[items.length];
    itemstemp[0] = ".NET";
    itemstemp[1] = "Android";
    for (int i = 2; i < items.length; i++) {
        itemstemp[i] = "";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < itemstemp.length; j++) {
            if (items[i].equals(itemstemp[j])) {
                selected[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void showDialog(View v) {
    selectedTech = "";
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick a Language");

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (selected[i]) {

                    selectedTech = selectedTech + items[i] + " ";
                    selected[i] = true;
                }
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.techView);
            tv.setText(selectedTech);
        }
    });

    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, selected,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    selected[which] = isChecked;
                }
            });
    builder.show();
}
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.multichoiceitem"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

this is mulchoice item and it contains the checkbox.
just run the code if you face any problem ask me.
it is a very easier process..

Comment: I am trying to find a way to implement this using a CursorAdapter. Your post does not answer my question.

Comment: yes i know but first of all checkbox in listview does not give you correct choice. That means if you check a checkbox and then scroll down and again scroll up then the check will disappear. So please use this it is very easier process and I am using it. Thank you.

Comment: That is exactly the scope of my problem, I believe it is much more enlightening to stare into a problems eye rather than shy away :)

Answer (score 0):

You create an like

```
List<Integer> positionList
```

and adapter getviewMethod

```
checbox.setCheckedChanged method in 
positionList.add(position);
```

and

```
for(Integer int:positionList){
if(int==position){
yourCheckBox.setChecked(true);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but this may be helpful to somebody.
If you're extending `SimpleCursorAdapter`, you will notice that the textviews inside the items of your `ListView` don't repeat themselves. Only the checkboxes do. Inside your adapter's class, you need:

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> checkBoxStates = new ArrayList<>();
```

Inside the constructor, put:

```
for(int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
    checkBoxStates.add(i, false);
}
```

and override the `getView()` method as follows:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                    checkBoxStates.set(position, true);
                }else{
                    checkBoxStates.set(position, false);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxStates.get(position));
        return view;
}
```