# ListView Data got cleared on scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working on a application which shows `listView` with `checkBoxes`.
When I scroll the `listView` the Value of `CheckBoxes` got Cleared.

Below is my code

*adapter class:*

```
public class Conference_listViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public static List<Model> data = null;
    ArrayList<String> id_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ViewHolder holder;
    int pos;

    public Conference_listViewAdapter(Activity context,List<Model> list, ArrayList<String> id_list) {
        data = list;
        this.id_list = id_list;     
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position).getName();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return Long.valueOf(id_list.get(position));
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.people_list_item1, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avtaar);
            holder.favorite = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.fav);
            holder.favorite.setTag(position);
            view.setTag(holder);

            holder.favorite.setTag(data.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).favorite.setTag(data.get(position));
        }


        holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {                    
                Model element = (Model) holder.favorite.getTag();
                element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());     
                //notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        holder.favorite.setChecked(data.get(position).isSelected());
        holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getName());



        try {
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(openPhoto(Long.valueOf(id_list.get(position))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView model;
        ImageView image;
        CheckBox favorite;
    }


}
```

*data model class*

```
public class Model {

    private String name;
    private boolean selected;

    public Model(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        selected = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

Don't know where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: i guess you are not using notifydatasetchaned() method

Comment: You can do this way:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29208904/4693713

thanks..

Comment: getting error > Implicit super constructor ArrayAdapter<Model>() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Comment: call `super(....)` inside your constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the state of the `ViewHolder`. Then set the `tag` when `convertView == null` and get it in the `else` condition.

Check the way I did:

```
public class Conference_listViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
    Activity context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public static List<Model> data = null;
    ArrayList<String> id_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    int pos;


    public Conference_listViewAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list, ArrayList<String> id_list) {
        super(context, R.layout.people_list_item1, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = list;
        this.id_list = id_list; 
    }



    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;       
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.people_list_item1, null);
            final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avtaar);
            holder.favorite = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.fav);

            view.setTag(holder);

            holder.favorite.setTag(data.get(position));

            holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {                    
                    Model element = (Model) holder.favorite.getTag();
                    element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());     
                }
            });


        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).favorite.setTag(data.get(position));
        }





        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();     
        holder.favorite.setChecked(data.get(position).isSelected());
        holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getName());

        try {
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(openPhoto(Long.valueOf(id_list.get(position))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
    }




    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView title;
        protected CheckBox favorite;
        ImageView image;
    }
```

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: why are you setting `tag` two times `holder.favorite.setTag(position);` & `holder.favorite.setTag(data.get(position));` ?

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working for me

Comment: Why to extend  ArrayAdapter<Model> ?

Answer (score 0):

change this..

```
  @Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

to..

```
  @Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}
```

Update:

try this..

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.people_list_item1, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avtaar);
        holder.favorite = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.fav);
        holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {                    
               //do what you want..   
            }
        });

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.favorite.setChecked(data.get(position).isSelected());
    holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getName());



    try {
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(openPhoto(Long.valueOf(id_list.get(position))));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: tried not working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

In similar situations like listview with checkboxes,radiobuttons,count box etc I use to do as follows
1) keep an arraylist with a size similar to the listview(number of rows)
2) this array/arraylist will be initialized in the constructor of adapter class with all positions as zero
3) inside getView() after declaring checkbox and setting its tag as position

```
public class Conference_listViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public static List<Model> data = null;
    ArrayList<String> id_list = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> myarray=new java.util.ArrayList<String>();   
    ViewHolder holder;
    int pos;


    public Conference_listViewAdapter(Activity context,List<Model> list, ArrayList<String> id_list) {
        data = list;
        this.id_list = id_list;
        this.context = context;
for(int i=0;i<id_list.size();i++)
myarray.add("0");
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.people_list_item1, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avtaar);
            holder.favorite = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.fav);
            holder.favorite.setTag(position);
            view.setTag(holder);

if(myarray.get(Integer.parseInt(holder.favorite.getTag().toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("1")
//make your checkbox checked
else
//keep checkbox unchecked
            holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {                    
   if(  isChecked)                   myarray.set(Integer.parseInt(holder.favorite.getTag().toString()),"1");    

else
myarray.set(Integer.parseInt(holder.favorite.getTag().toString()),"0"); 

notifydatasetchanged();
            });

            holder.favorite.setTag(data.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).favorite.setTag(data.get(position));
        }


        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        holder.favorite.setChecked(data.get(position).isSelected());
        holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getName());



        try {
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(openPhoto(Long.valueOf(id_list.get(position))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView model;
        ImageView image;
        CheckBox favorite;
        Boolean selected;
    }   

}
```

always this saves my issues with listview scrolling..

Comment: I am not getting this, can you modify it in my code?

Comment: @yushi check the edits

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error, I think. You need to set this code
`holder.favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()` outside the if/else block. The reason is whether **convertView is = null** or not, the listener should be set. I realize your code may need bit of arrangement but I think you could do that better than me since my code style is different. Is this clear enough though?

Another possible error is `holder.favorite.setTag(position)`. The reason is code `Model element = (Model) holder.favorite.getTag()` in your listener. You're saving the int `position` and typecasting it to the `Model` class, could not work. Change the override **getItem**, first coding to do. Sample code in summary:

```
@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);   // return the Model
    }
...
holder.favorite.setTag( getItem(position) );
```

Note: Again **holder.favorite.setTag** should be set **outside** the if/else block. Only view.setTag(holder) could be set in the if block because it's a new view object.

Besides all this, I think your code design should work!

> Suggested code changes...

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

ViewHolder holder = null;    // different

if (convertView == null) {
   ...
   holder.favorite.setTag(data.get(position));    // different
   view.setTag(holder);                           // different

}
else {
   view = convertView;
   holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();    // different
}
...
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
   Model element = (Model) buttonView.getTag();    // different
```

Changes are:

1. I use comments of **different** to emphasize code changes.
2. `ViewHolder holder` is declared here in `getView`(). Remove the holder declaration on top inside the class. I think this is better coding style since holder is closer to find where you're using it, make it local to getView.
3. The placement of `holder.favorite.setTag` and `view.setTag` is switched. I think this is a **safer** coding style. I think it is safer to set the holder first before using it as a parameter to object view. It may not matter, I admit.
4. `view.getTag` is necessary when **convertView is not = null**. When you set the tag with `view.getTag()).favorite.setTag` in the same block, you're actually changing the content of the holder with unexpected behavior.
5. In code `(Model) buttonView.getTag()`, buttonView is used instead of holder.favorite.  I hope this gets the correct Model object.

Comment: Sometimes I do post sample code, but I need to do some stuff now.

Comment: I just finished my posted updates under "Suggested code changes". I hope it makes sense for you also. We both can make mistakes.

Comment: Oh..remove the code "ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();" under the else block. You no longer need that code in that place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73827/discussion-between-yushi-and-the-original-android).